# Adding extra buying option to product

Tags: commerce

I need to add extra buying option with some price in Create Product (Add a product). If a user checks on extra buying option then they need to add the price and that price will be again added to product price. I am trying to achieve this using [commerce pricing attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes) but no success so far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use Product Attributes & Variations.
full documentation is here: 
https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Commerce Product Add-on](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado) and it worked like a charm